# atlassian plugin sdk: maven dependency of dependency not resolving

Tags: java, spring, maven, atlassian-plugin-sdk

Currently I am developing a JAVA plugin for (Atlassian) Bitbucket. But I'm fairly new to Maven, and it's dependency management.

Right now I have the following dependency declaration in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
    <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I try to run (using `atlas-run`), I will get the following error when the system tries to enable the plugin:

> [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2017-09-18 17:43:40,422 ERROR [spring-startup] c.a.plugin.osgi.factory.OsgiPlugin Detected an error (BundleException) enabling the plugin 'com.atlassian.bitbucket.plugin.HotfixMes.HotfixMes-Plugin' : Unresolved constraint in bundle com.atlassian.bitbucket.plugin.HotfixMes.Plugin [32]: Unable to resolve 32.0: missing requirement [32.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.jdi).  This error usually occurs when your plugin imports a package from another bundle with a specific version constraint and either the bundle providing that package doesn't meet those version constraints, or there is no bundle available that provides the specified package. For more details on how to fix this, see https://developer.atlassian.com/x/mQAN

Trying to read this, it looks like the dependency `com.sun.jdi` is not loading. This is what I don't get:

1. Firstly: this works when I have a "clean" java application without it being a Bitbucket plugin. So no dependency issues there
2. I can not find which "sub-dependency" would need it, but I am sure that it has something to do with the org.telegram.telegrambots, since the error only occurs when I have that dependency enabled.

Could somebody point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

It's very important to specify the scope of dependencies in jira plugin development, so please try the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
    <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```